# How to Add a "Like" Button to my FaceBook Landing Tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My FaceBook Page is setup so that users who have not "Liked" the page yet (and attempt to view the page) are presented with the content of a particular tab instead of the default "wall" view.

The tab that these users arrive at contains an application I made. It is a simple application that lists information about the business.

The application is using the "I Frame" render method (in the application's "Canvas" settings).

**My goal is to add a FaceBook "Like Button" or "Like Box" inside my application.**

The purpose of this is to write a message that encourages visitors to "Like" the FaceBook Page (not the application).

I've tried the FaceBook code generators for Like Buttons and Like Boxes, but it does not work. When I view my application in FaceBook, there is "nothing" in the location where I added the code.

Having a "Like" button inside of an application seems like something that many FaceBook page owners would want. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to be more clear. You are want to add a like button into you application tab and not the application itself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you page is loaded in html mode instead of FBML.

1, Load the FB JS

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOURAPPID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

2, Init the FB (sometimes it doesn't work without this)

```
<script>
FB.init({
    appId:"YOURAPPID",
    xfbml:true,
    status:true,
    cookie:true,
});
</script>
```

3, Put the like button where do you want

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

The like will appear, but will not make page refresh, so you have to take care the flow yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently like buttons aren't supported in the current implementation of FBML, which is the only language you can use inside the "tabs" on a facebook canvas page.
You may notice that a number of professionally done sites put a big arrow pointing up and then a "click the like button" text, without actually using a like button. This is why they do that.

Until facebook implements XFBML inside tabs, it looks like any XFBML only tags (such as fb:like) can only be used on your personal website. I think they do this for security reasons, although it does seem a little ridiculous that there are features you can use on your own page that facebook doesn't actually support on -their- pages.

The only workaround I have found is to include fb:comments tag in your app, which is an FBML tag that puts up a comments box AND a like button.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get a Like button, go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like, fill out the appropriate information and press "Get Code". This will open up a modal window with the necessary code. Copy that code into your program, and you're done.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but "nothing" appears in my application where I pasted in the code.

Comment: I would need more information about your application, how you're writing it, where you're pasting the code, etc.