# Add Like Button To My Web site

Tags: web-applications, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement the Facebook "Like" button for my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854051/how-to-implement-the-facebook-like-button-for-my-website)
>   [How to Add a "Like" Button to my FaceBook Landing Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469918/how-to-add-a-like-button-to-my-facebook-landing-tab)

can you please give me detailed info on how to add a like button to my website page, just made my first web page so am a novice.  Clicked on add like button but it doesn't tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Facebook developer pages. They have simple tools that generate code that you can copy/paste in your website code.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and 
make the Step 1, enter the URL of your site and click "Get Code".. Copy the code and paste for the place as you want in you source code page HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Simple copy this HTML code to every page you need a Like button:

```
<script>(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=157629837654379&xfbml=1";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```